# ExtJS DateFormat Issue

Tags: sql, datetime, extjs, format, gridpanel

I haven't found an existing question on this exact problem (there were several that were similar but did not help).

I have a GridPanel with exam results, including when the exam was complete.  The date returned from the SQL server is formatted like '**yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.uuu**' (2011-04-15 19:45:13.197).

My problem is that even though the time is 19:45, it always displays as 7:45 AM.

The dateformatter I am using in the datastore is '**Y-m-d H:i:s**' and '**F j, Y, g:i A**' in the column model.  I have tried several different options in the datastore and none of them make a difference, if they even work at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following: In the Store use `type:'date', dateFormat: 'c'` in the column use `xtype: 'datecolumn', format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'` that work for me.

Comment: Sorry, it still says 7:45 AM.

Comment: @cmhampton please confirm that your date format in the store is something like this: `Date {Mon May 09 2011 15:09:00 GMT+0000}` and provide some example code about how you trying to display it.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot.  There was a typo in my server side JSON encoding function.  Once I fixed it, everything works perfectly.  Sorry to waste your time sra.

Comment: @cmhampton No problem! Everytime again